# Plot mean of measurements with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have a file of measurements that I am planning to plot with pgfplots. There are multiple measurements for each input:

```
Size        Time
100           599.3
100           598.0
100           597.7
100           597.9
100           596.3
100           592.6
100           593.1
100           600.3
250         21423.3
250         21479.8
250         21353.4
250         21333.7
250         21322.7
250         21262.6
250         21395.5
250         21873.0
250         21400.9
```

etc.

When I try to plot them naively, I get one point for each measurement, which makes the plot look bad.

The question is: how do I plot just the average for each input size?

Comment: There is `\pgfmathaccuma` function in pgfplots and pgfplotstable. Maybe you can use it to average the values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an external shell command.

First of: I use Linux and gawk, I am not sure how easy it is to get this working on Windows. But in principle you can use any other external program (e.g., python or C code) that way. Using the plot shell command like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}
  \addplot shell {awk '/^[0-9]/
                  {if($1!=x&&length(x)!=0){print x, y/n;x=$1;y=$2;n=1}
                   else{x=$1;y+=$2;n+=1;}}
                  END{print x,y/n}' file.dat};                                                                                                      
 \end{axis}                                                                                                 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

When compiling you need to make sure to add the `-shell-escape` option:

```
 pdflatex -shell-escape file.tex
```

---

#### Reference:

Chek out section 4.3.6 - "Computing Coordinates with External Programs (shell)" in the [manual](http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/pgfplots.pdf) for more information.

Link to [Gawk for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/gawk.htm)

---

#### EDIT:

If you want to add the sample standard deviation to the data, you can use the shell command together with table, which is neat:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}
  addplot+[error bars/.cd, y dir=both,y explicit] table[x index=0, y index=1, y error index=2] shell 
      {awk '/^[0-9]/{if($1!=x&&length(x)!=0){print x, y/n, sqrt((n*sy-y*y)/n/(n-1));x=$1;y=$2;sy=$2*$2;n=1}
       else{x=$1;y+=$2;sy+=$2*$2;n+=1;}}            
       END{print x,y/n, sqrt((n*sy-y*y)/n/(n-1))}' tmp.dat};                                                                                                      
 \end{axis}                                                                                                 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @jens_bo, your first solution works nicely for me. Unfortunately when I tried your second solution I got `! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
<to be read again> 
                   ^
l.2639       {awk '/^
                     [0-9]/{if($1!=x&&length(x)!=0){print x, y/n, sqrt((n*sy`. Any chance you could supply a minimal working example of your second solution? Thanks.